# Remove first and last character at the same time using regex in R

Tags: regex, r

I have a string as follows:

```
" 12.32%".
```

I want to remove the blank space and the percentage. I can remove the % using

```
gsub("%", "", mystring)
```

How do I remove the blank space in front at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a [**character class**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) is fine. Saying — "match **one** character specified by the class".

```
gsub('[ %]', '', ' 12.32%')
# [1] "12.32"
```

Comment: why not stick with the character class you showed before?

Comment: would you mind explaining the difference. I get the character class -- I'm confused by the alternation?

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to regex, if you plan to convert these strings to numeric later, `scan()` is a nice clean way to do both operations at once.

```
scan(text = " 12.32%", comment.char = "%", quiet = TRUE)
# [1] 12.32
```

This strips the white space, flushes the line at `%`, and converts to class "numeric" all in one go.  If you don't want to convert to numeric, add the argument `what = ""`

Answer (score 1):

```
x<-" 12.32%"    
gsub("%|\\s","",x)
    [1] "12.32"
```